# autoreconf got an error: required file './test-driver' not found

Tags: autotools

when running autoreconf I get this error

```
parallel-tests: error: required file './test-driver' not found
parallel-tests:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'test-driver'
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 7):

autoreconf has an option --install (short version -i), by using this options some missing dependencies will be installed automatically.  This is a nice option to remember.  Several other errors can be fixed by this option.

```
autoreconf -i
```